# How to paint (or do it opaque) a background of ImageIcon for JToggleButton?

Tags: java, swing, togglebutton, imageicon

I would like to pass an image on JToggleButton but I do not know how to paint or do opaque its background

```
ImageIcon iFontBold     = new ImageIcon("resources\\FontB.png");
ImageIcon iFontItalic   = new ImageIcon("resources\\FontI.png");

JToggleButton tbBold   = new JToggleButton();
tbBold.setIcon(iFontBold);
JToggleButton tbItalic  = new JToggleButton();
tbItalic.setIcon(iFontItalic);
```

[image]

Comment: The easiast way is to make the background color of image transparent